# создание jar архива с текстовыми файлами

Tags: java

При создании джава-архива для проекта содержащего текстовые файлы, текстовые файлы не добавляются в джава-аржив(лежат рядом с папкой src)

Answer (score 0):

Запуск из среды разработки и запуск упакованного jar файла - это разные вещи.

Во время запуска проекта из среды разработки файлы, путь до которых записан так "MyFile.txt" должен лежать рядом с папкой src. Если записать путь так "../MyFile.txt", то файл должен лежать рядом с папкой проекта.

Во время запуска свёрнутого jar файла, если прописан путь "MyFile.txt", то файл должен лежать рядом с jar'ником, если прописан путь"../MyFile.txt", то файл должен лежать рядом с внешней папкой, т.е. рядом с той, в которой лежит jar файл.

Вам легче всего будет прописать путь так "MyFile.txt", во время тестов класть текстовый файл в проект рядом с src, а перед упаковкой в jar файл достать текстовый файл и после упаковки положить его рядом.